Approximating exponential function using piecewise constant function
I want to construct a piecewise function to approximate the function $f:[0,1]^d \to \mathbb{R}, ~f(x) = \exp(\|x\|^2)$. My approach is to partition the space $[0,1]^d$ into non-overlapping cubes $B_1,\dots B_m$ with centers $b_1,\dots, b_m$ and radii $\delta_1,\dots, \delta_m$, and define the piecewise function by
$$
g(x) = \sum_{j=1}^m e^{\|b_j\|^2} 1\{{x \in B_j}\}.
$$
So for each $B_j$, we approximate $f(x)$ by it's value at the center $f(b_j)$. I want to choose $m$ large enough (or equivalently, the width of the $B_j$'s small enough) to ensure something like: for any $x \in D = [0,1]^d$
$$
c_1 g(x) \le f(x) \le c_2 g(x),
$$
so that my approximation is off by at most a constant factor. I'm struggling with the details though. My idea was to use the mean value theorem:
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x\in B_j} |f(x) - g(x)|
&=
\sup_{x\in B_j} |f(x) - f(b_j)|\\
&\le 
\sup_{x \in B_j}\|\nabla f(x)\| \|x - b_j\|\\
&\le 
\sqrt{d}\delta_j \sup_{x \in B_j}\|\nabla f(x)\|\\
&=\sqrt{d}\delta_j \sup_{x \in B_j}2\|x \|\exp(\|x\|^2)\\
&=\sqrt{d}\delta_j 2\|b_j + \delta_j \|\exp(\|b_j + \delta_j\|^2)
\end{align*}
We should then pick $\delta_j$ small enough to ensure that the final expression is smaller than $f(x)/2$. This would ensure something like
$$
\sup_{x\in B_j} |f(x) - g(x)| \le f(x)/2 \implies \frac{2}{3}g(x) \le f(x) \le 2g(x).
$$
To that end, we need to solve for $\delta_j$ satisfying:
$$
\sqrt{d}\delta_j 2\|b_j + \delta_j \|\exp(\|b_j + \delta_j\|^2) \le \frac{1}{2} \exp(\|b_j\|^2).
$$
Which I'm struggling to solve.

Is this approach reasonable?
If yes, how would I go about solving for $\delta_j$?
Does this approach guarantee to get the smallest choice of $m$ possible? or are there better alternatives?


Which norm are you using? If this is the 2-norm, I think you only have $|x-b_j| \le \sqrt{d}\delta_j$.

@gabalz thanks for noting that, i've updated the working

Do you need an explicit algorithm to find the $b_i$ and $\delta_i$, or just an existence proof?

@JairTaylor I am mainly interested in finding the exact order of m that makes it possible to do this. So it would be more than just showing existence, i would like to have an expression for m and $\delta_i$

$h(x) = \|x\|^2$ is continuous on the compact set $C = [0,1]^d$. For any given $\epsilon > 0$, and $c \in C$, there is some $\delta_c$ such that $h(B(c, 2\delta_c)) \subseteq (h(c)-\epsilon/2, h(c) + \epsilon/2)$, where $B(c,2\delta_c) = \{x : \|x - c\| < 2\delta_c\}$ is the ball of radius $2\delta_c$ about $c$.
The collection of all $B(c,\delta_c), c\in C$ forms an open cover of $C$, which by its compactness has a finite subcover $\{B(c_i, \delta_{c_i})\}_{i=0}^n$. Let $\delta$ be the minimum of the $\delta_{c_i}$. Now if any two points $x, y\in C$ are within $\delta$ of each other, then $x \in B(c_i, \delta_{c_i})$ for some $i$, and since $\delta \le \delta_i$, by the triangle property, both $x,y \in B(c_i,2\delta_{c_i})$, so both $h(x),h(y)$ are within $\epsilon/2$ of $c_i$, and therefore within $\epsilon$ of each other. I.e., for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x,y \in C, \|x - y\| < \delta \implies |h(x) - h(y)| < \epsilon$. $g$ is uniformly continuous on $C$.
If you take $\frac2{\sqrt d}\delta$ as the sidelengths of the cubes $B_i$ in your non-overlapping grid, then every point $x$ of $C$ will be within $\delta$ of the center $b_i$ of its cube, and therefore $h(b_i) - \epsilon < h(x) < h(b_i) + \epsilon$. Now $f = e^h$, so exponentiating, $e^{-\epsilon}f(b_i) < f(x) < e^\epsilon f(b_i)$. I.e.,
$$e^{-\epsilon}g(x) < f(x) < e^\epsilon g(x)$$
Note that I did not use anything about $\|x\|^2$ other than its continuity. If $f$ is any continuous positive function on $C$, then $h(x) = \ln f(x)$ is defined and continuous on $C$, and the same argument holds. So you can approximate any continuous positive $f$ in this fashion.
For your specific $h(x) = \|x\|^2$, it is not hard to find for any $\epsilon > 0$, what $\delta > 0$ you need to guarantee that if $\|x - y\| < 2\delta$, then $|\|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2| < \epsilon/2$.

shouldn't it be that if we take $\sqrt{2}\delta$ as the side lengths then every $x$ will be within $\sqrt{d} \delta$ of the corresponding center? If I am understanding the rest correctly, using reverse triangle inequality we can take $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon/8d}$ to ensure the last line of your answer holds

No. Actually, it should have been if we take $\frac{2}{\sqrt d}\delta$ as the sidelengths, then every $x$ will be within $\delta$ of the center. I was thinking of the plane when I wrote it. It is necessary to pick the sidelengths so that $x$ is within $\delta$ for the needed result. But the particular details are not important. What is important is that it is possible to pick some cube size that fits in balls of radius $\delta$. Any smaller size will work as well.
